# Arrays variable in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to array concept there is something i cant understand that is i have read somewhere that when we intialize an array like `int[] a = {1,2,3,4} ;`

then a actually contain the address of memory location of the the first element of that array
I havent statrted oop yet but as i know when toString method is used on reference variables it converts the value of an object that the reference variable contains its address to string but why when use

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a));
```

the whole array is printed rather than just first element of array a ? because array a contains the address of first element only

Comment: Java doesn't work like C; in Java memory address is not relevnt

Comment: because the code for the `Arrays.toString(...)` method is written to display the entire array

Comment: I dont know anything about C programming and i am learning java by myself

Comment: So `a actually contain the address of memory location of the the first element of that array` is wrong, you can't have read that about Java

Comment: No i havent , i read that on a page about arrays so it is only like that in C progrmming?

Comment: You seem to mention the terms *address* or *memory location* a lot, but in Java these are generally of little relevance. I suggest you study the [basics of arrays in the Java language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array was printed because you called `Arrays.toString(int[] a)` method
Which is implemented by JAVA API
[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
 * The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements,
 * enclosed in square brackets (<tt>"[]"</tt>).  Adjacent elements are
 * separated by the characters <tt>", "</tt> (a comma followed by a
 * space).  Elements are converted to strings as by
 * <tt>String.valueOf(int)</tt>.  Returns <tt>"null"</tt> if <tt>a</tt> is
 * <tt>null</tt>.
 *
 * @param a the array whose string representation to return
 * @return a string representation of <tt>a</tt>
 * @since 1.5
 */
public static String toString(int[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

For more clarity related to arrays memory representations,
Kindly check the below diagram:

[image]

Comment: So it is right that the reference  variable a contains the address of the first element of the array? Does this also applies in java and it is not only specific for C programming as @azro mentioned?

Comment: @Marwa no, an array in Java is more that just a  pointer/memory address.

Comment: @Hulk isnt array variable just a container which contains the address of an actual array?

Comment: @Marwa short answer "Yes", long answer "No" because as Huk said the array in Java is more than just a pointer/memory address, for example, it adds functionality to knows the array length and random access to any object inside the array

Comment: It is an object that contains a lot more than just the actual contents like methods for sorting, accessing, deleting, ... contents and properties like lenght, ...

Comment: @ahmednabil88 
datatype[] arrayVariableName =new datatype[size]
So now the arrayVariable name contains the address of the array object right?
So an object is created in a memory location with the specified address? 
Do each individual element of this array have their own address? Or the whole array only will have the address corresponding to it?

Comment: @Marwa yes,  each individual element of this array have their own address, and for more clarity, I will add a diagram which describes memory representations (in both cases "array contains objects" and "array contains primitaves")

Comment: @Marwa if the answer is useful for you, can you mark it as an accepted answer?

Comment: So the adresses of each elements are different from that of array object?

Comment: @Marwa sure, that is true

Answer (score 2):

In Java, arrays are more than just memory adresses. Rather, they (and basically everything else in Java) are objects with certain methods and properties. So, when calling `Arrays.toString(a)` (and similarily `a.toString()`), this actually calls a special method specialized on printing arrays, and that method just prints every element.

Edit: Here is a quick entry tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score -1):

Well,
The reason it prints all values of the array is a is an array. When we execute

System.out.print(Arrays.toString(a))

we didn't specify which element of array to print so it displays the entire array. a points to first element address.